# NLog on ASP.NET MVC 4: NLog or NLog.Web

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, nlog

I'm new to [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). Would you recommend to use NLog or NLog.Web for an ASP.NET MVC 4 project? I see that NLog.Web can be used for standard ASP.NET projects but not sure about MVC ones.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Mvc/ ?

Comment: Don't need to write to a database, isn't it what NLog.Mvc is all about?

Comment: You can still add your own targets to log to (e.g. File) if you don't want to use database. You also get some attributes to automatically log exceptions

Comment: NLog is good enough,

Comment: NLog.Mvc does not work in VStudio 2013 and 2015. I've just downloaded the complete source code from https://github.com/MikeHanson/NLog.Mvc. The application fails to start.

Comment: I am now trying this approach: https://cmatskas.com/nlog-with-sql-server-and-mvc-4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/) assembly is good enough to start logging in your asp.net mvc app. You can log your messages to a log file. If you need database logging in your asp.net web app, you need 2 more assemblies

1. [NLog.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extended)
2. [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web/)

`NLog.Web` is needed to get data from the HttpRequest. So one can say this is optional unless you really want the details from HttpRequest (why not) ?